# GitHub Actions fails with: "An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory"

Tags: github-actions, kubectl

The Error from GitHub:

```
An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/myproject-api/myproject-api/app'. No such file or directory
```

My Workflow File:

```
name: Docker Build and Push to Docker Hub and ghcr.io

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'feature/auto-deploy-dev'

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: app

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.SECRET }}
          password: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
          push: true
          file: Dockerfile
          tags: |
            repo/project:latest

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: KubeCtl Command
        uses: tale/kubectl-action@v1
        with:
          base64-kube-config: ${{ secrets.KUBECONFIG }}
      - run: kubectl get pods -n myNamespace
```

Comment: Please mention the step from which that error is coming. Also, there are two `checkout` steps.

Comment: Error Coming from last step 
```name: KubeCtl Command uses: tale/kubectl-action@v1```

Comment: You set your default `working-dir` as `app`. Looks like after your second checkout the path is not what you expect it to be. Also, the second checkout seems redundant, you might want to remove that. As for `tale/kubectl-action`, it updates the K8s configuration. That error seems to be occurring during its shell initialization.

Comment: I dont know what path Github actions is expecting. Imho it does not matter for executing kubectl commands.

Comment: Yes, running `kubectl` shouldn't be an issue. Where is that error coming from? Step title?

Comment: I removed the "defaults.run.working-directory: app" and now it works for all steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the "defaults.run.working-directory: app" and now it works for all steps. The error messages are gone.